# Sort properies inside array

Tags: php, string, sorting, explode

I'm getting an error message `Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in`

I want to sort the properties here...

Super easy but not working yet... minor tweak needed here :

```
$css = <<<EOF

z-index : 9;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
line-height: 10px;

EOF;

echo implode ( ';', ( sort ( explode( ';' , $css ) ) ) );

/* Expecting to get :

line-height: 10px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
z-index : 9;

*/
```

Pretty much self explanatory :)...

Small tweak would make this work :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`sort`](https://www.php.net/sort) function returns a `bool`. Also, exploding / imploding on `';'` won't give you quite what you want. Try using `"\n"` instead:

```
$arr = explode( "\n" , $css );
sort($arr);
echo implode ( "\n", $arr );
```

If you want to do this all in one line you can write a custom function, like this:

```
function my_sort($arr) {
    sort($arr);
    return $arr;
}
```

And then you can call it like this:

```
echo implode ( "\n", my_sort( explode( "\n" , $css ) ) );
```

Comment: So basically I CAN NOT use this in the same line so I have to make external function to make it work in single line ?

Comment: @user3447293 You could write a custom function that returned the original array. See my updated answer.